# hive is not working with HDP with Ambari

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have installed the HDP with Ambari 2.6.1. It mostly did everything automatically but Hive is unable to start properly.

I saw a post somewhere and I deleted the pid and killed the process as well in hope that I would restart it and it would work but now it's showing heartbeat lost on the machine.

Please guide me on what should I do?

I am listing the errors I got from ambari.

1.Hive Metastore:

```
    Metastore on machine2.ambari.local failed (Traceback (mos&1| awk '{print}'|grep -i -e 'Connection refused' -e 'Invalid URL'' returned 1. Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://machine2.ambari.local:10000/;transportMode=binary: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0) Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://machine2.ambari.local:10000/;transportMode=binary: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0) )" data-bindattr-40693="40693"> Connection failed on host machine2.ambari.local:10000 (Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HIVE/0.12.0.2.0/package/alerts/alert_hive_thrift_port.py", line 212, in execute ldap_password=ldap_password) File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/functions/hive_check.py", line 81, in check_thrift_port_sasl timeou... t recent call last): File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-servics/HIVE/0.12.0.2.0/package/alerts/alert_hive_metastore.py", line 203, in execute timeout_kill_strategy=TerminateStrategy.KILL_PROCESS_TREE, File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 166, in __init__ self.env.run() File "/
```

2. Hive Server2:

   ```
   awk '{print}'|grep -i -e 'Connection refused' -e 'Invalid URL'' returned 1. Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://machine2.ambari.local:10000/;transportMode=binary: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0) Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://machine2.ambari.local:10000/;transportMode=binary: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0) )" data-bindattr-40693="40693"> Connection failed on host machine2.ambari.local:10000 (Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HIVE/0.12.0.2.0/package/alerts/alert_hive_thrift_port.py", line 212, in execute ldap_password=ldap_password) File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/functions/hive_check.py", line 81, in check_thrift_port_sasl timeou...
   ```

Comment: Please add the logs under `/var/log/hive` on `machine2.ambari.local` to your question

Comment: There's nothing in that directory :/

Comment: Well, Ambari won't show you why the process won't start... The logs are somewhere on that machine. Otherwise you can try to manually run Hive services under /usr/hdp/current/

Answer (score 0):

There are following three different issues in this question

1. Hiveserver2 alert :Following error indicate port `10000` on `machine2.ambari.local` is not reachable, either there is no process (HiveServer2) running on port `10000` or some proxy issue.

   Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://machine2.ambari.local:10000/;transportMode=binary: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2. Heartbeat Lost : In question it is mentioned that "heartbeat lost on the machine", this could be because `ambari-agent` process is no more running on host for which heartbeat lost is notified.
3. After deleting the pid and killing the process , by default it will not restart automatically.